# Conversão de struct com struct aninhado para record

Tags: c, struct, delphi-xe5

Estou com um pequeno "entrave" em um projeto que estou trabalhando. Nós recebemos uma DLL escrita em C, para podermos nos comunicar com leitores dessa empresa. 
 Em anexo, veio um exemplo escrito em Borland C++ 6, que funciona corretamente. O problema consiste em usar essa DLL com o Delhpi XE5. Uma das rotinas devolve como resultado de sua operação um struct que tem outro aninhado. Segue abaixo os structs como definidos no Borland C.

```
struct stChannelInfo
{
  char ReaderTag[16];
  char ReaderEnabled;
 }

 struct stChannel
 {
   int ReaderNumber;
   struct stChannelInfo *ChannelInfo;
 }
```

A rotina que recebe esse *struct* é essa:

```
stChannels = this->deviceInterface->LookForAvailableChannels(EdDirectorySource->Text.c_str(), iSn, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);  
for(int i = 0; i < stChannels.ReaderNumber; i++)  
 {  
   CLbChannels->Items->Add(stChannels.ChannelInfo[i].ReaderTag);  
 }
```

Eu escrevi este *record* que seria o equivalente em Delphi:

```
type stChannelInfo = record  
 ReaderTag : string[16];    
 readerEnabled : char ;    
end;

type stChannel = record    
 ReaderNumber:integer;  
 ChannelInfo : ^stChannelInfo ;  
end;
```

E a rotina que recebe o *record* em Delphi ficou assim :

```
DadosCanais := LookForAvailableChannels (Pchar(dirroot) , sn , datepickerinicial.DateTime,datepickerfinal.DateTime);
for i := 0 to (DadosCanais.ReaderNumber-1) do
 begin
  Showmessage(DadosCanais.ChannelInfo^.ReaderTag);
  inc(DadosCanais.ChannelInfo);
 end;
```

Pelo pouco que eu entendi do Borland C, o loop le da rotina lê os vários valores de `stChannel.ChannelInfo.readerTag`, mas em Delphi a string que eu recebo perde sempre o primeiro caracter e vem preenchida com espaços.

A definição de uso da rotina segundo o manual é esta:

```
/*
 Efetua a busca na base de dados de todos os canais do aparelho
 indicado que possuem dados disponíveis no intervalo selecionado.  
 Version:  
 1.00  
 Parameters:  
 *dataBaseFolder caminho da base de dados  
 serialNumber numero de serie do aparelho  
 firstLogTime timestamp inicial  
 lastLogTime timestamp final  
 Returns:  
 stChannel Retorna uma estrutura com o numero de readers disponíveis e
 seus tags. Em caso de problemas, a estrutura terá o parâmetro 
 "ReaderNumber" zerado.  
*/
struct stChannel LookForAvailableChannels (const char * dataBaseFolder, 
     int serialNumber, double firstLogTime, double lastLogTime)
```

Como eu poderia acessar os dados das tags dos readers? Não consigo imaginar uma forma para ler esses valores.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu recebi de Remy , uma ajuda que estou postando aqui. Adaptei ligeiramente para o meu caso mas funcionou perfeitamente para este caso.

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}

 Type
  PstChannelInfo = ^stChannelInfo;
  stChannelInfo = record
  ChannelTag: array[0..CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH-1] of AnsiChar;  // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
  ChannelEnabled: AnsiChar;  // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
 end;

// Structure with information about channels
 stChannel = record
  ChannelNumber: Integer;  // Número de canais no buffer
  ChannelInfo: PstChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
 end;

 stChannels := Self.deviceInterface.LookForAvailableChannels(PChar(EdDirectorySource.Text), iSn, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);  
 for i := 0 to stChannels.ChannelNumber-1 do   
  begin
   CLbChannels.Items.Add(stChannels.ChannelInfo[i].ChannelTag);  // Add to list the values found  
  end;
```

Alternatively:

```
 Type
  PstChannelInfo = ^stChannelInfo;
  stChannelInfo = record
  ChannelTag: array[0..CHANNEL_TAG_LENGTH-1] of AnsiChar;  // Tag (máx 16 caracteres)
  ChannelEnabled: AnsiChar;  // Habilitado se diferente de "0"
 end;

 // Structure with information about channels
  stChannel = record
  ChannelNumber: Integer;  // Número de canais no buffer
  ChannelInfo: PstChannelInfo;  // Buffer com informações dos canais
 end;

 PstChannelInfoList = ^TstChannelInfoList;
 TstChannelInfoList = array[0..MaxInt-1] of stChannelInfo;
 stChannels := Self.deviceInterface.LookForAvailableChannels(PChar(EdDirectorySource.Text), iSn, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd);
  for i := 0 to stChannels.ChannelNumber-1 do  
   begin
    CLbChannels.Items.Add(PstChannelInfoList(stChannels.ChannelInfo)^[i].ChannelTag);  // Add to list the values found
   end;
```

Comment: Você pode aceitar sua resposta.